# Is there any relationship between input length and hash distribution?

Tags: hash, hashtable, probability

I test some hash function in [this site](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) with Canterbury corpus benchmark set.

In the test, my program reads benchmark file

For each one byte, consecutive 3 or 4 byte will be the input of hash function

example) benchmark file contain "ABCDEFGHI"

when input length is 3, 'ABC' is the first input and generate some hash value

next, 'BCD' is the second input and generate another hash value and so on

when input length is 4, input will be 'ABCD' and next, 'BCDE'

hash output is 32bit long, and my program extract the last 12 bit and this 12 bit is used as a address of hash table

I test Rotation hash, One-at-a-time hash, Bernstein's hash, FNV hash.

when input length is 4, the hash utilization is always better than when input length is 3 in every test case.

Is there any relationship between input length and hash distribution?
any theory or characteristics of hash?

or just coincidence?

Comment: By "hash utilization" do you mean "space utilization", "load factor", or something else? What exactly are you calculating, and what numbers do you get?

Comment: How many different 3-grams do you hash? How many different 4-grams? And I agree with @JohnFeminella: what *exactly* are you measuring?

Comment: I calculate (the number of hash entry that something written) / (total number of hash entry) and input length 4 shows higher value.

Comment: hmm.. I didn't check the n-gram information.

Comment: You should post your code, input and output, as there are *many* ambiguities in your question about what you've done and what the results have been that aren't worth talking through....

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an underlying array which is resized whenever the hash table gets too "full." Usually the size of the underlying array is picked off a list of primes which are each about twice the size of the previous size. There are lots and lots of ways to do this, but the point is that for a given resizing scheme, if you just add elements one-by-one the utilization will vary up and down, but will probably go down immediately after resizing.

Comment: Did you mean that the table can be resized dynamically? 
in my experiments, the table size is fixed